# Hidden achievements in Jetpack Joyride

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

I have completed all the achievements except the hidden achievements. Can somebody tell me those achievements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean these, here you are:

[image]

EDIT:

These should also be secret achievements.

[image]

Comment: These are only 4 but there are total 7 secret achievements.

Comment: @DeMize I've probably found other 2 of them. See the edit.

Comment: Thanx for that but i need 1 more

Comment: @DeMize which platform are you playing? Because on JJ wikia there are only 5 hidden achievements: Tee Hee Two, Blinged Out, Pretty Woman, Dragon Fruit and Walkies.

Comment: I've just checked on iOS and the in-game achievement list only shows Tee Hee Two, Pretty Woman, Walkies, and Blinged Out as secret. All the others show their criteria on the list. (I can't verify if they're secret on Game Center because I've already got them all.)

Comment: I rechecked and there were only 6 secret achievments so thats all